# Grouping rows together to see if the transaction record contains a refund

Tags: sql-server

```
(TransactionID, UserID, Type, OrderNumber, Amount)

1, 123, Purchase, 100, 100
2, 123, Refund, 100, 100
3, 234, Purchase, 101, 100
4, 345, Purchase, 102, 100
```

I want to create a query that will return all transactions, grouped by a userID that don't currently have a return for the given OrderNumber.

I need to make a refund transaction for every user, and I don't want to make a refund if one already exists.

Is it possible to order and group such that I can find those transactions?

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.UserID = t1.UserID AND t2.Type = 'Refund');
```

The logic of the above query reads simply as return all transaction records for a given user where we cannot find a single record belonging to the same user which was a refund.

Answer (score 1):

You can also group records like this using conditional aggregation.

```
create table Transactions (TransactionID int, UserID int, [Type] varchar(20)
 , OrderNumber int, Amount int)

insert into Transactions values
(1, 123, 'Purchase', 100, 100),
(2, 123, 'Refund', 100, 100),
(3, 234, 'Purchase', 101, 100),
(4, 345, 'Purchase', 102, 100)

Select UserId
, max(CASE WHEN  [Type] ='Purchase' then Amount ELSE 0 END) as PurchaseAmount
, max(CASE WHEN  [Type] ='Refund' then Amount ELSE 0 END) as RefundAmount
from Transactions
group by UserID
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1441756387d5b7c13879992da9d06147) demo.

Answer (score 0):

With the tables suggested by @Suraj, the following SQL should give you the refund amount by user

```
select pur.UserID, 
    RefundAmount = sum(pur.Amount - Isnull(refund.Amount, 0))
  from Transactions pur
    left join Transactions refund 
        on pur.UserID = refund.UserID 
                    and pur.OrderNumber = refund.OrderNumber
                    and refund.Type = 'Refund'
 where pur.Type = 'Purchase'
 group by pur.UserID
```